# How to get HDL Designer Series library contents in tcl script?

Tags: vhdl

I can get a list of the libraries in an HDL Designer Series project with the following command on the tcl console:

```
library names
```

Is there a similar command to get a list of the library contents?  Not the actual files, but the design units (e.g. entity or package), just like what is displayed in the gui.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct command like $library names.  There are library and file object properties that have the design unit names.  The object structures are listed in the HDL Designer Series Command Reference.

This gives a list of the files in a library (file objects, not the actual files):

```
$lib files
```

So looping through those to get the declarations of each file:

```
$file declarations
```

And then looping through those and getting the name of each gives the design units.

```
$declaration configure name
```

There's an example of how to loop through them in the HDL Designer Series Tcl Reference Manual.